# Remove specific sub string in a string with regex expression in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm quite new to the regex world and I'm struggling with this problem. I'd like to remove the specific word in a string. I was able to remove last n characters in this way:

`gsub('.{5}$', '', mystring)`

like this

```
mystring = "HOBBIES_1_001_CA_1"
newstring= "HOBBIES_1_001"
```

Now I wanted to remove the central sub string in this way:

```
mystring = "HOBBIES_1_001_CA_1"
newstring= "HOBBIES_CA_1"
```

Any help is appreciate thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substring` as it would be faster

```
substring(mystring, 1, nchar(mystring)-5)
[#1] "HOBBIES_1_001"
```

To remove the middle string, match the `_` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by the `_` and digits and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("_\\d+_\\d+", "", mystring)
#[1] "HOBBIES_CA_1"
```

Or another option is to capture the substring and replace with the backreference

```
sub("^([^_]+)_\\d+_\\d+", "\\1", mystring)
#[1] "HOBBIES_CA_1"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract string in 2 parts using `sub`. The first part is letters `[A-Z]` before first underscore and second part is `[A-Z]` followed by a number at the end of the sentence.

```
sub('([A-Z])_.*?([A-Z]+_\\d+)$', '\\1_\\2',mystring)
#[1] "HOBBIES_CA_1"
```